# Project WGS84 to Google using MapGuide and WKT

Tags: coordinate-system, google-maps, well-known-text, mapguide

I'm having trouble projecting a simple WGS84 formatted layer over google maps. I can't find a good WKT "API" that not only shows parameters, but explains what each parameter is.

The coordinate system of the MapDefinition I am using is:

```
GEOGCS[
    "GCS_WGS_1984",
    DATUM[
        "D_WGS_1984",
        SPHEROID["WGS_1984",6378137.0,298.257223563]
    ],
    PRIMEM[
         "Greenwich",
         0.0
    ],
    UNIT[
        "Degree",
        0.0174532925199433
    ]
]
```

The PROJCS that I started writing but won't validate:

```
PROJCS[
    "Popular Visualisation CRS / Mercator",
    GEOGCS[
        "GCS_WGS_1984",
        DATUM[
            "D_WGS_1984",
            SPHEROID[
                "WGS_1984",
                6378137.0,
                298.257223563
            ]
        ]
        PRIMEM[
            "Greenwich",
            0.0
        ]
        UNIT[
            "Degree",
            0.0174532925199433
        ]
    ],
    PROJECTION["Mercator_1SP"],
    PARAMETER["central_meridian",0],
    PARAMETER["scale_factor",1],
    PARAMETER["false_easting",0],
    PARAMETER["false_northing",0],
    AUTHORITY["EPSG","3785"],
    AXIS["X",EAST],
    AXIS["Y",NORTH]
]
```

For some reason mapguide won't validate this. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is the typo "SPHEREOID" in the original?

Comment: @whuber - Yes, thank you. It still won't validate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try putting commas between DATUM, PRIMEM, and UNIT

Comment: +1, specifically before `PRIMEM` and `UNIT` (2 in total)

Comment: Oh my gosh! How did I miss that? Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
PROJCS[
    "Popular Visualisation CRS / Mercator",
    GEOGCS[
        "GCS_WGS_1984",
        DATUM[
            "D_WGS_1984",
            SPHEROID[
                "WGS_1984",
                6378137.0,
                298.257223563
            ]
        ],
        PRIMEM[
            "Greenwich",
            0.0
        ],
        UNIT[
            "Degree",
            0.0174532925199433
        ]
    ],
    PROJECTION["Mercator_1SP"],
    PARAMETER["central_meridian",0],
    PARAMETER["scale_factor",1],
    PARAMETER["false_easting",0],
    PARAMETER["false_northing",0],
    AUTHORITY["EPSG","3785"],
    AXIS["X",EAST],
    AXIS["Y",NORTH]
]
```